# Redirect without loop

Tags: loops, redirect, href

I have a dropdown menu that grabs the href of another dropdown and saves it to a variable. How can I redirect the page using window.location.replace() with out it looping.

```
let deutsch_link = '';
$('.lang_list_class li a').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == "Deutsch" || $(this).text() == "Deutsche" || $(this).attr("data-language") == "de") {
    deutsch_link = $(this).attr("href");
    console.log(deutsch_link);
    
    window.location.replace(deutsch_link);
         
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `windows.location.replace` is executing the redirection in there.
you could try

```
$(this).attr("href", deutsch_link)
```

so the redirection happens when the `a` tag is actually clicked. If not, let me know a little bit more about the requirement, maybe I am understanding it the wrong way.